# Tag Manager to two ga properties

Tags: analytics, google-tag-manager

I have implemented Google enhanced Ecommerce Via GTM for GA Property (New), keeping the old classic analytics code in the webiste, Now I removed the old classic code and pushing the events data from the same GTM account to (old) GA property (Replicated the Tags with different GA Property, Reference url : http://www.kristaseiden.com/step-by-step-adding-a-second-ga-property-via-google-tag-manager/).

The first GA property transactions are used to track properly, But after adding another GA property the transactions and all other events are not tracking accurately. In both the accounts Transactions are dropped to 50 percent.

Could someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom JS variable:

```
function() {
  var newTrackingId = 'UA-XXXXXX-XX'; // Replace here
  var globalSendTaskName = '_' + newTrackingId + '_originalSendTask';
  return function(customModel) {
    window[globalSendTaskName] = window[globalSendTaskName] || customModel.get('sendHitTask');
    customModel.set('sendHitTask', function(sendModel) {
      var hitPayload = sendModel.get('hitPayload');
      var trackingId = new RegExp(sendModel.get('trackingId'), 'gi');
      window[globalSendTaskName](sendModel);
      sendModel.set('hitPayload', hitPayload.replace(trackingId, newTrackingId), true);
      window[globalSendTaskName](sendModel);
    });
  };
}
```

And then add this as a custom task on fields to set:

[image: fields to set]

Hope it helps!

**PS:** Here is a more [detail post](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/send-google-analytics-tag-multiple-properties/) from Simo Ahava.

Comment: Thanks Marco,I will try this solution. And I would like to know why the approach I folllowed is not working accurately.  - Thank you

Comment: @RaviTeja Sadly i don't have a good answer. When you mix implementations GTM make strange things.